# Yii2 remove div tags from NavBar

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to build admin panel based on Admin LTE, it uses bootstrap 4.0. I'm using a `NavBar` in my `main.php` yii2 layout like this:

```
 <?php
    NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => Yii::$app->name,
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'main-header navbar navbar-expand bg-white navbar-light border-bottom',
        ],
    ]);
    echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav'],
        'items' => [
            ['label' => '', 'url' => ['/site/index'],'options'=>['class'=>'nav-item'], 'template' => '<a href="#" class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>'],
            ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about'],'options'=>['class'=>'nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block']],
            ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact'],'options'=>['class'=>'nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block']],
        ],
    ]);
    NavBar::end();
    ?>
```

The expected output is

```
<nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand bg-white navbar-light border-bottom">
    <!-- Left navbar links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
        <a href="index3.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

But i end up with stuff like this in html:

```
<nav id="w0" class="main-header navbar navbar-expand bg-white navbar-light border-bottom">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header"><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#w0-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.php">My Application</a>
      </div>
      <div id="w0-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
         <ul id="w1" class="navbar-nav nav">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="/index.php?r=site%2Findex" data-widget="pushmenu">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block"><a href="/index.php?r=site%2Fabout">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block"><a href="/index.php?r=site%2Fcontact">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

How can i get rid of this `<div class="container` and div with `.navbar-header`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `$renderInnerContainer` for the `NavBar` see [**`Docs`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/doc/api/2.2/yii-bootstrap-navbar#$renderInnerContainer-detail)

change your code to

```
 <?php
    NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => Yii::$app->name,
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'renderInnerContainer'=>false,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'main-header navbar navbar-expand bg-white navbar-light border-bottom',
        ],
    ]);
    echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav'],
        'items' => [
            ['label' => '', 'url' => ['/site/index'],'options'=>['class'=>'nav-item'], 'template' => '<a href="#" class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>'],
            ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about'],'options'=>['class'=>'nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block']],
            ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact'],'options'=>['class'=>'nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block']],
        ],
    ]);
    NavBar::end();
    ?>
```

You cannot turn off the `navbar-header` container as it is hardcoded in the `init()` function of the `yii\bootstrap\NavBar` line `123` you can extend and override the `NavBar` if you want to remove it. or you can alternatively use css class to override all the properties if its some issue with adjusting the width